# Serilog Sinks BrowserHttp problem with ingest

Tags: serilog

I'm developing in ASP.NET Core Blazor WebAssembly.

Originally I had made a Blazor wasm project in Visual Studio 2019 where client, server, and shared were all part of the same project.

The project grew and I decided to split up the project into separate git repos.

I'm using Serilog.Sinks.BrowserHttp and it was working fine before I split up the project.

Now I'm getting an error in Console (Chrome):

[image: [Serilog.Sinks.BrowserHttp](1)]

Before the project was split up into two separate git repositories, all logging was saved in the database, but after the split, only the server-side logs are being stored in the database.

Is there a way I can store the logs straight into my Microsoft SQL database after having split up the Blazor project?

Here is my Program.cs logger configuration:
[Logger Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ygttt.png)

I just figured since both server and client were both in the same project and everything worked fine, the problem must be that the logger is assuming they still are in the same folder.

Comment: What handles `/ingest` on the server-side? Have you installed/configured _Serilog.AspNetCore.Ingestion_? (Need some more detail :-) )

Comment: I am using the server-side relay to handle ingestion with Serilog.AspNetCore.Ingestion. This package is referenced inside the server.csproj. In the server startup.cs I am calling app.UseSerilogIngestion(). Unlike the sample on github for Serilog.Sinks.BrowserHttp, there is no project reference to the client-side anymore since it is part of a different repository. I havent configured Serilog.AspNetCore.Ingestion at all.

Comment: Setting the endpoint of the logger configuration to another path changes the POST error to that path 404.

Comment: _I havent configured Serilog.AspNetCore.Ingestion at all. _ sounds like it will be your problem; check out: https://github.com/nblumhardt/serilog-sinks-browserhttp/blob/dev/samples/Server/Startup.cs#L45 - HTH!

Comment: Thanks, I check startup.cs on the Server side and I'm using app.UseSerilogIngestion(); there. Do I need to make any adjustments to the SerilogIngestionOptions or SerilogIngestionMiddleware in order for the server to receive logs from the client side? Right now the default SerilogIngestionOptions.EndpointPath is /ingest.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was an old Nuget packet Serilog.Sinks.BrowserHttp 1.0.0-dev-00012. When selecting to manage nuget packets for my solution in Visual Studio, under package description the only version available is the installed version. But from the command line I was able to update to the lastest version 1.0.0-dev-00021.